# Filtrar notificaciones en Odoo11

Tags: odoo

Tengo un item de menu que llama a al action de las notificaciones de email de Odoo, pero necesito que solo sean notificaciones especificas, no todas como me salen ahora, como puedo hacer?
gracias de antemano. Estoy trabajando con Odoo11

Answer (score 0):

Se resolvió así, con un action server se llama desde el item de menú, y el action server llama a una función desde el modelo que tiene un domain con el filtro que se queria

```
<menuitem name="Notification List" id="id_menu_item" parent="menu_parent" action="id_action_server" sequence="1"/>

<record id="id_action_server" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Mail_notification_container</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_reference" />
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code"> action=model.get_function()
        </field>
<record>

@api.multi
def get_function(self):
    return {
        "name": "Container notification",
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "res_model": "mail.mail",
        "views": [(False, "tree"),(False, "form")],
        "domain":['|',('//aqui se pone el fltro por el body del mensaje')],
        "target":"custom",
        }
```

Listo